# ReactJS Email Button Giving Wrong Input

Tags: reactjs, email, button, href

Below I put a screenshot of some ReactJS code that is a button that is linked to an email address.

I was wondering why this code was not working properly when I click on it.

```
<a href={`mailto:${item.email}`}>
   <CardAction>
      Contact Me
   </CardAction>
</a>
```

I tried the above solution and when I clicked the button, it led to my email application but did not input any email into the "send" spot.

Comment: could it be because your `item.email` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Use `body` and `subject` like query parameters to set the body and subject of the email:

```html
<a href={`mailto:${item.email}?body=the_body_of_my_email&subject=the_subject_of_my_email`}>
   <CardAction>
      Contact Me
   </CardAction>
</a>
```